# Spring Security Namespace

Tags: spring, spring-security, namespaces

I am new to Spring Security and I was trying to add spring security namespace. Do I need to add this to serverlet-context.xml. In my Eclipse>Spring MVC project it looks like that is the only file that has namespace information. The other two xml files are web.xml & root-context.xml.

Where do I put the namespace information?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how your app is split up and what you want to secure. The `web.xml` file is not a spring configuration file so you can't put Spring Security configuration in there. Putting it in the `servlet-context.xml` should be OK.

However, if you are at this stage, you should probably start with [one of the sample applications](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/tutorial-xml). Also take a look at [this getting started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) on spring.io which uses Java configuration with Spring Boot which is a much nicer combination.

Comment: Thanks both link looks pretty good, the second one though configures in Java way. Id like to avoid that - in preference of xml way of configuring things. But nice links, thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid Java configuration?

Comment: Two reasons. It gets pretty cluttered as the configurations become big as the applications grows and scales. Second I want to avoid what I believe would be a JVM overhead if there are so many method invocations and new class creations.

Comment: More cluttered than XML? I don't think so. Do you have some evidence that there is any more overhead than using XML? Parsing XML is a lot slower than executing Java methods and the net result is the same from your app's perspective, once it is configured.